# Error in deploying custom changes in Docker Identity Server- SC10.3

Tags: docker

I am trying to deploy some custom changes in Sitecore identity server in docker environment for xp0 which includes a dll and some config changes.
It works fine in non docker environment but I am getting error while deploying it in docker. **Any idea how to fix this**

**The error is:**
`

```
Creating sc_id_1         ... error
ERROR: for sc_id_1  Cannot start service id: container 23212ef4141818014d2fbce23b1949f2756b0ff86dcaa59a5d8e7b9ad0544121 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]

ERROR: for id  Cannot start service id: container 23212ef4141818014d2fbce23b1949f2756b0ff86dcaa59a5d8e7b9ad0544121 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6DBFE9FCB: (caller: 00007FF6DBF9E19A) Exception(1) tid(38c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**My docker for for identity server looks like:**

```
# escape=`

ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG TOOLING_IMAGE


FROM ${TOOLING_IMAGE} as tooling
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
 
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 
# Copy development tools and entrypoint
COPY --from=tooling \tools\ \tools\
COPY .\servicestart.ps1 \service\
```

**And docker-compose.override file contains:**

```
id:
    environment:
      WORKER_EXECUTABLE_NAME_ENV: servicestart.ps1  
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-id:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/id
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-id7:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        TOOLING_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_TOOLS_REGISTRY}sitecore-docker-tools-assets:${TOOLS_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_DEPLOY_PATH}\id:C:\deploy
        
    entrypoint: powershell -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1 @{ Path= \"C:\\deploy\"; Destination = \"C:\\identity\"; }"
```

Comment: I never had any success using the development entrypoint

Comment: Actually development works for me because I used it for xconnect custom deployment where it works. I feel there is something wrong with the line 'COPY .\servicestart.ps1 \service\' in docker file.

Answer (score 0):

The base image for sitecore-id7 has changed and is now using `windows/nanoserver` which only has `pwsh` not `powershell`.

The next issue you'll run into is that `robocopy` is not available which is required by `C:\tools\entrypoints\worker\Development.ps1`.

If you change it to use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-windowsservercore` as the base image so that you have robocopy, it will appear to work but then you run into a fundamental issue that the web server process has to be restarted to pick up any changes anyway.

**So you're better off not using this file watcher at all and just build a custom image with your code.**

### In case you really want to get this file watcher to work:

**docker-compose.override**

```
id:
  image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-id:${VERSION:-latest}
  build:
    context: ./docker/build/id
    args:
      BASE_IMAGE: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-windowsservercore-${EXTERNAL_IMAGE_TAG_SUFFIX}
      ID_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-id7:${SITECORE_VERSION}
      TOOLING_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_TOOLS_REGISTRY}sitecore-docker-tools-assets:${TOOLS_VERSION}
  volumes:
    - ${LOCAL_DEPLOY_PATH}\identityserver:C:\deploy
    - ${LOCAL_DATA_PATH}\identityserver:C:\Identity\logs
  environment:
    WORKER_EXECUTABLE_NAME_ENV: Start.ps1    
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "powershell", "-command", "C:/Healthchecks/Healthcheck.ps1"]
    timeout: 300s
  entrypoint: powershell -Command "& C:\\tools\\entrypoints\\worker\\Development.ps1 -WatchDirectoryParameters @{ Path = \"C:\\deploy\"; Destination = \"C:\\Identity\"; }"
```

**docker\build\id\Dockerfile**

```
# escape=`

ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG ID_IMAGE
ARG TOOLING_IMAGE

FROM ${TOOLING_IMAGE} as tooling
FROM ${ID_IMAGE} as id
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}


SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

COPY --from=id \Identity\ \Identity\
COPY --from=id \Healthchecks\ \Healthchecks\

# Copy development tools and entrypoint
COPY --from=tooling \tools\ \tools\
COPY .\tools\entrypoints\Start.ps1 \service\

USER ContainerAdministrator
EXPOSE 80
```

**docker\build\id\tools\entrypoints\Start.ps1**

```
dotnet.exe c:\identity\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll
```